# Batch file spaces in variable with if else

Tags: batch-file

I have this code here:

```
:a
set /p unit=Unitpile Entry:
echo %unit% >> unitpile.txt
if %unit% EQU exitscript (
goto b  
) else (
goto a
)
```

and whenever %unit% has a space in it, so it's two words, the file closes.
Help please... or is it something to do with syntax.
BTW I do have all other appropriate labels, it's just this is a snippet of the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your batch code with some comments. You can see here how to use double quotes right.

```
:a
rem Define environment variable unit with a double quote as default value.
set "unit=""
set /p "unit=Unitpile Entry: "
rem Remove all double quotes entered by user. If the user has not entered
rem anything, the default double quote is removed. The default is necessary
rem in case of user enters nothing to make the next line working also in
rem this special case.
set "unit=%unit:"=%"
rem Has the user entered anything at all?
if "%unit%"=="" goto :EOF
echo %unit%>>unitpile.txt
if /I "%unit%"=="exitscript" (
    goto b
) else (
    goto a
)
:b
```